# Fetch data using a dropdown and two textboxes

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to fetch a row from database table with the help of a dropdown and two different textboxes. Here I just want to search a student from a database students table to find a student with the help of the values from the form: class, division and roll no. Can anyone please guide me how to achieve that? I just want to fetch student name and want to display that name to the Student Name element on form page itself.
Here is the UI: [Desired implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYtPo.png)
Here is the code that I tried so far:

**get_student_name.php**

```
<?php 
        ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        
        require_once("includes/config.php");
        if(!empty($_POST["class"]) && !empty($_POST["division"]) && !empty($_POST["rollno"])) {
          $class= $_POST["class"];
          $division= strtoupper($_POST["division"]);
          $divisionNoSpaces = str_replace(' ', '', $division);
          $rollno= $_POST["rollno"];
          $rollnoNoSpaces = str_replace(' ', '', $rollno);
         }
            $sql ="SELECT FullName,Status FROM tblstudents WHERE Class=:class AND Division=:division AND Rollno=:rollno LIMIT 1";
        $query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
        $query-> bindParam(':class', $class, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query-> bindParam(':division', $divisionNoSpaces, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query-> bindParam(':rollno', $rollnoNoSpaces, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query-> execute();
        $results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        ?>
```

**form**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Class<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<select class="form-control" id="class" name="class" required>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Nursery">Nursery</option>
    <option value="KG-I">KG-I</option>
    <option value="KG-II">KG-II</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
</div>    
<div class="form-group">
<label>Division</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="3" id="division" name="division" autocomplete="off" required />
</div>    
<div class="form-group">
<label>Roll Number</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="rollno" name="rollno" maxlength="5" autocomplete="off" required />
</div>    
<div class="form-group">
<label>Student Name</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="studentName" name="studentName" maxlength="5" autocomplete="off" readonly />
</div>    
<div id="studentNameDiv">
</div>    
<div class="form-group">
<label>ISBN Number or Book Title<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="booikid" id="bookid" onBlur="getbook()"  required="required" />
</div>    
 <div class="form-group">    
  <!--<select  class="form-control" name="bookdetails" id="cc" readonly>       
 </select>-->
 </div>
<button type="submit" name="issue" id="submit" class="btn btn-info">Issue Book </button>
```

**JS ajax function:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#rollno').keyup(function(){
        var rollno = $('#rollno').val();
        var classname = $('#class').val();
        var division = $('#division').val();
      if (rollno != '' || classname != '' || division != '') {
         $.ajax({
            url:"get_student_name.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{
                Class:classname, 
                Division:division, 
                Rollno:rollno},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){
                //alert("Success");
                $("#studentNameDiv").html(data);
            }
        });
     } else {
        $("#studentNameDiv").html('NoNe');
     }   
  });
});
```

Database table columns: Class, Rollno, Division

Comment: What doesn't work in your current code?

Comment: Please explain the specific problem you're experiencing currently

Comment: I am fetching student name from the ajax but it is not getting displayed inside the readonly textbox.